# Which tool for Android to find & manage duplicate files without cleaning aim?

Tags: multiple-devices, unwanted-files

I am searching for a tool for Android which can universally help to manage duplicate files, triplicate files etc.

At end perhaps to select some for deletion - but at end, and perhaps.

All tools I found combine finding duplicates with cleaning, and emphasize deletion. Thus all are not usable.

The reason for my trouble is that once again on my SD card (plugged in the slot of Samsung Galaxy 10+, Android 12) very many files are lost or are rearranged.

Partly this may be due to my rearrage activities for bringing files into new created directories by not only copy but rather by command move.

Thus the simplest application of a find-duplicates tool I need is:

Files are directly under /storage/3530-3234.

Created new directory
/storage/3530-3234/WEsubdir.

Now not directly to move the files into the new directory, but to run search. In the list of search results to mark the files, and to copy the files without move. Then to use a find-duplicate tool to prove if copying was correct.  Then to delete according to the search-result list.

When a tool each time start to scan the whole storage device, as most known tools do, that is not the right way. I need to control what range_1 of storage device_a is to be compared with what range_2 of storage device_b regarding duplicates.

Neither in Android nor in Linux are usable tools available, as I found.

Please does someone know a tool, a solution.

Regards

Comment: Please note that questions asking directly for software recommendations are off-topic. This question has been migrated to our sister site. Consider visiting and joining the site to regain ownership of your question there. Thanks for your understanding.